# What are the various reasons for "Not Sent" emails in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, tracking-extract

I ran a tracking extract on a journey send for all those "not sent" and was curious about the possible reasons an email would receive that classification.

Here are the reasons in my tracking extract: Held, list detective exclusion, suppression list exclusion, unsubscribed (Email was sent as transactional so not sure how unsub is relevant).

We also see 653 unsent in journey builder and the tracking extract only showed 588 in the csv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Held and unsubscribed are both statuses subscribers can have in Marketing Cloud.

**Held**: Three or more bounces, soft or hard, are received for the subscriber and more than 15 days have passed since the first bounce.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5

**Unsubscribed**: An unsubscribed status prevents all sends to the recipient unless you configure the system to allow transactional sends only, for example, a receipt of purchase.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5

Here are the remaining ones you mentioned:

**List Detective**: List Detective is a tool that maintains information on email addresses and domains that could cause deliverability problems for your email sends.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_list_detective.htm&type=5

**Exclusion List**: An exclusion list is any list, group, or data extension you create in the application that at the time of send you select to exclude from the send.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_exclusion_list.htm&type=5

**Suppression List**: A suppression list is a list of subscribers that you don't want to receive your communications.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_suppression_lists.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks, Zuzanna.  Do you have any idea why we see the discrepancy between journey builder and the tracking extract?  653 "not sent" in journey builder and 588 in "not sent" tracking extract.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where the discrepancy comes from, it would be best to play around with SQL and Data Views and check how many went through the email send activity vs. how many were actually sent an email