# Auto-suppression reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, email-tracking, autosuppressionlist, datorama

We have implemented auto-suppression in our parent BU down to all BU in order to suppress email sends to Russia. This is working fine. When the system tries to send an email, it just suppress this contact from the send, for example, if you send to 2 contacts and 1 is in auto-suppression, you will see only 1 contact sent to in tracking.

Now, I don't see anything to report this. I checked Discovery reports, tracking extract, but I don't see an out of the box way for knowing when I tried to send to this auto-suppression list. I am thinking of just comparing people I sent to to my auto-suppression. Does anybody know if there is a better option? perhaps Datorama in the future?

Comment: You could export the auto-suppression list records but this only gives you a list of records. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318185&type=1

In tracking history will show you which list have been excluded but not sure you can click on the number and export it.

Comment: The only other thing I can think about is an SQL query between the sending DE and autosuppression list to get your results. 
However might be easier to do it with dataviews and not job specific based on contact key otherwise a query will need to be created for each send and its not sustainable.

Comment: Thanks, I think dataviews is a suitable option

Comment: @SYUYDY tracking extract is probably our best bet here 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324669/what-are-the-various-reasons-for-not-sent-emails-in-journey-builder