# Email "Not Sent" View in Journey Builder Email Analytics of SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have run a journey that is sending a Newsletter to a set of contacts, In Email Analytics it is showing a "Not Sent" view to some of the contacts.
Is there any way that I can debug why the Email has not been sent to those contacts?
I am not using any AmpScript in Email Body.

Comment: please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/324672/28187, likely those contacts are unsubscribed or hardbounces